# How do I obtain a list of all videos in a channel using the YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API 3 for a client and am not getting all current videos.

The API Explorer has 4 results:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&channelId=UCwB4tpXCMWi-bw5HpMlY6Bg&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

And here is the client YouTube page: http://www.youtube.com/user/goldensteinart/videos
which has 7 videos.  They must all be public or they wouldn't appear on the page, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: I also ran into the same issue. Please see this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040885/youtube-api-v3-cannot-retrieve-all-videos-from-a-channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040885/youtube-api-v3-cannot-retrieve-all-videos-from-a-channel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API call that you should make if you want to get the videos in a channel is a `youtube.playlistItems.list()` with the playlistId of the "uploads" playlist for the channel. (This usually stars with `UU...`, but that's an implementation detail that might change in the future.

Here's an example of the call in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUwB4tpXCMWi-bw5HpMlY6Bg&_h=2&).

Getting the same data via a search operation isn't guaranteed to return everything; the search index isn't a replacement for the backend data that you can obtain via the `youtube.playlistItems.list()` call. It's very much the same point raised in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html) (though the focus there is on v2).

We just posted a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M) talking about how to get the videos in a channel, and there's samples illustrates how to make the actual API calls from your code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).