# Google Youtube API Search doesn't retrieve all videos in the channel

Tags: youtube-api

I have to retrieve all video of my channel with Youtube API.
All videos are published on Youtube and I can see them correctly.

I tried to make the request directly from this page: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
and this is the example request:
GET http s://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=myChannelID&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Request doesn't retrieve all videos, it returns only 7 on the total of 9.
All videos have the same configuration. Missing videos are always the same.

If I use the video API passing the ID of one of those videos excluded from the search response, it returns a correct response and it belong correctly to my channel:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it

Someone can help me?

thank you in advance

Francesco

Comment: What's your channel ID? That way we can run the same tests you are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to "How do I obtain a list of all videos in a channel using the YouTube Data API v3?" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489109/4892731) may be what you need. Look especially at the video linked to in the answer.

To summarize, to get all the uploads from a channel, you need to get the items from the uploads playlist for the channel using playlistItems.list on that playlist's ID rather than calling search.list on the channel ID.

Try this two-step approach:

1. Get the ID of your channel's uploads playlist using the channels.list API call: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
2. Get the videos from the uploads playlist using the playlistItems.list call: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=3&playlistId={YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Thank you, it was my second solution to solve the problem. Even if I didn't understand why search API doesn't work properly.

Comment: @mmirus playlistItems.list() works from some uploadId , throws 404 for other saying playlist not found. search.list() works for all but returns old videos.

Comment: @DevsYakamoz: did you find a way to list all videos (especially chronologically) using search?

Comment: @mmirus in the playlistItems endpoint how to use some date range parameter like publishAfter/ publishedBefore. I tried It, not working So how I fetch all the videos of a channel.

Comment: This solves my problem as well when searching for video's of a channelId and order on date. Which gives unreliable results (randomly missing latest video's). And the quota cost for getting the channels lists and playlist items is only 1 for each call. Which is important nowadays when the daily quota is decreased to 10.000

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
async static Task<IEnumerable<YouTubeVideo>> GetVideosList(Configurations configurations, string searchText = "", int maxResult = 20)
{
    List<YouTubeVideo> videos = new List<YouTubeVideo>();

    using (var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = configurations.ApiKey
    }))
    {
        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = searchText;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = maxResult;
        searchListRequest.ChannelId = configurations.ChannelId;
        searchListRequest.Type = "video";
        searchListRequest.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date;// Relevance;


        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();


        foreach (var responseVideo in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            videos.Add(new YouTubeVideo()
            {
                Id = responseVideo.Id.VideoId,
                Description = responseVideo.Snippet.Description,
                Title = responseVideo.Snippet.Title,
                Picture = GetMainImg(responseVideo.Snippet.Thumbnails),
                Thumbnail = GetThumbnailImg(responseVideo.Snippet.Thumbnails)
            });
        }

        return videos;
    }

}
```

Comment: the ides is the configration like type and searchText