# Google Youtube API provides wrong data

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a trouble with YouTube API. I have an experience in many API services and first time I encountered such strange work of this API.

Problem description:

First, I want to get subscribers of my channel. I'm developing this tool for my friend, but I take my own channel for testing purposes. So, doesn't matter how (through Web Interface of my C# tool), but I always get wrong data about my subscribers.

This is my json response:

```
    ...
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 17,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
    }, ...
```

Actual count of subscribers is 17. It is ok. But next, I have a list with subscribers description:

```
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#subscription",
   "etag": "...",
   "id": "...",
   "subscriberSnippet": {
    "title": "chris chandler",
    "description": "",
    "channelId": "UCbl-PjR7SwAQkGi2nUlZbMg",
    ...
   }
  },
```

And count of this blocks is 8.
I tried to set ***maxResults*** to 50 for getting all results in one page. But I always have 8 subscribers. I don't know why.

I tried tool with my friend's account. His actual count of subscribers is 385. But API shows only 301. Also I tried to get list of my subscriptions. Actual it is 107, but I get only about 80.

I've tested it with Web interface here:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=subscriberSnippet&maxResults=5&mySubscribers=true

**P.S. You can think, that some of YouTube data doesn't update momentarily. But I have constant amount of subscribers on my test channel about 3 years (It is about channel with 17 subscribers).**

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: no, i didn't. It just returns wrong data... I think, it is problem with API

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471390/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-videos-in-a-channel-using-the-youtube-data-api-v3?lq=1) if it can help you:)