# Videos missing from a channel's video list

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve information about all the videos of a given YouTube channel.

Here is my first request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=50&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/15j9AlxbMtzBhzffpA04ahJgv9g\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "FR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 375,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    "... 50 items here ..."
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is a total of 375 results. So, using the `nextPageToken`, I search for the 50 next videos.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=50&pageToken=CDIQAA&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/7mmGfmqsGmfP8OggZWZVefQ7z6Q\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CGQQAA",
  "prevPageToken": "CDIQAQ",
  "regionCode": "FR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 375,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    "... 28 more items here ..."
  ]
}
```

There are only 28 items in this response. Furthermore, if I query for the next page:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=50&pageToken=CGQQAA&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This time, there are no items at all.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/XKJQFk8Z_J6XraQ0mVCRtVWnSYc\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CJYBEAA",
  "prevPageToken": "CGQQAQ",
  "regionCode": "FR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 375,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
  ]
}
```

What causes this behavior? Is there something wrong with my request?

Comment: In order to reproduce the problem it could be useful to know {CHANNEL_ID} value  that has caused this issue in your tests. I just tried through the apis-explorer page and with the `channelId: "UCsGakFIbOsj-fgPFLf1QlQA"` without any problem. Also in my case I've authorized requests using OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Here is the channel ID I'm trying to query: `UCRVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A`, and I've been authorizing requests with an API key, although I suppose it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: just to provide more information I confirm that in the reported channel: `UCRVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A` let me reproduce the problem while this problem does not seem to exist for same other channels such as `UCsGakFIbOsj-fgPFLf1QlQA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `YouTube Data API v3` you should:

### Step 1: get your channel's upload playlist

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCRVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

`json
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/8HOHPc1ZO5cOiePp8nFHwKA99HM\"",
   "id": "UCRVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UURVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A",
     "watchHistory": "HL",
     "watchLater": "WL"`

The **uploads** playlist for your channell is `UURVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A`

### Step 2: use youtube.playlistItems.list to get all videos uploaded in yout channell by specifying the `playlistId` of your channel's `uploads` playlist

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken={WHEN_YOU_HAVE_A_PAGETOKEN_PUT_IT_HERE}&playlistId=UURVDPcrF_LTJo8u0bkzUL9A&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

---

#### with reference to answers to questions:

- [youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930200/youtube-api-v3-list-uploaded-videos)
- [how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-videos-in-a-channel-using-the-youtube-data-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471390/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-videos-in-a-channel-using-the-youtube-data-api-v3)

---

#### about the behavior of `Search: list` API

as documented here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list about search result property `pageInfo.totalResults`I quote literally:

> The total number of results in the result set.Please note that the
>   value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In
>   addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use
>   the nextPageToken and prevPageToken property values to determine
>   whether to show pagination links.

also, by some investigations I did testing it seems that the videos that are "missing" in the result, as you indicated, however, appear in the results when the optional parameter `q` is explicitly specified in the request, obviously only if the  filter value specified can be satisfied by the data of the video in question.