# YouTube API v3 Search not returning all videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve all videos for a channel, and some are not being returned by the api. I cannot find anything in the spec that indicates why some would not be in the result set.

The call I'm making is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&key=__key_here__&channelId=UCxS2lX7728bTnmK1t21bYlA&part=id,snippet&maxResults=50&order=title
```

[To test this you'll need [your own api key]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

The first page of results is missing at least one video. The one from 8-15-2018, titled [I LEARNED HOW TO DO A NEW TRICK!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRaFy_7cmUY), which is located here, is not in the result set, even though it falls within the date range, and the first 50 results.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue?

I have verified that if I add the q parameter, with the video id, it will retrieve it.

Answer (score 3):

You may refer with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489109/5832311).

> The API call that you should make if you want to get the videos in a channel is a `youtube.playlistItems.list()` with the `playlistId` of the "uploads" playlist for the channel. (This usually stars with `UU...`, but that's an implementation detail that might change in the future.
>
> Here's an example of the call in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUwB4tpXCMWi-bw5HpMlY6Bg&_h=2&).
>
> Getting the same data via a search operation isn't guaranteed to return everything; the search index isn't a replacement for the backend data that you can obtain via the `youtube.playlistItems.list()` call. It's very much the same point raised in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html) (though the focus there is on v2).

To summarize, to get all the uploads from a channel, you need to get the items from the uploads playlist for the channel using `playlistItems.list` on that playlist's ID rather than calling `search.list` on the channel ID.

Comment: I'm trying to get the videos from someone else's channel. Will it be possible to use this method in that case?