# Get a YouTube channel uploaded video list by publish date

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**I am aware of similar questions being asked before, but not this exact one, so please bear with me...**

I want to reproduce a channel's uploaded videos list as they appear on YouTube's web page (broken into pages and sorted by publish date).

To do this, I am trying to get a list of VideoIDs from a YouTube channel that's sorted by publish date (by YouTube, not my code since there could be 1000's of videos in a playlist and YouTube limits to 50 results per query which can add up when I only want to show the user the first 25 entries).

Initially, I was using this YouTube Data API v3 Search query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[APIKey]&channelId=[ChannelID]&part=snippet,id&order=date&type=video&maxResults=25
```

However, as some of the previous posts on stackoverflow mentioned ([YouTube API v3 Search not returning all videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808721/youtube-api-v3-search-not-returning-all-videos)), this method does not guarantee to return all videos and indeed, some videos are missing from the result, making use of this query problematic.

I then saw this google video in some of the posts:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M

In the video, it is explained that you must first get the 'uploads' playlist for a channel (I'm also grabbing the channel's title and thumbnail in this query), which I do using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=[APIKEY]&part=snippet,contentDetails&id=[ChannelID]
```

And once I have the 'uploads' playlist ID, I query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=[APIKey]&playlistId=[PlaylistID]&part=snippet,id&order=date&type=video&maxResults=25
```

However, the returned entries are **not sorted by the publish date** and according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), there is no optional "order" parameter associated with this query.

With all these issues in mind, how do I get the first 25 entries of the 'uploads' playlist sorted by publish date without downloading the entire playlist so I can faithfully recreate how the YouTube website is listing videos.

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: @abielita This URL (remember to use a valid APIKEY) shows a channel with the upload video playlist is not sorted by publish date https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=[APIKEY]&playlistId=UU1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ&part=snippet,contentDetails&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId,videoPublishedAt),snippet/title,status)&maxResults=25

Answer (score 3):

After making some tests and thanks to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57179/207498) *(and the next answers too)* I was able to retrieve the information you need using the YouTube Data API v3 and here is how I made it:

First, in your question you're using the ["search" API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en) - since I don't know which criteria you're using in the search request, I omitted it for get direct to get the "`upload`" playlist id from a given `channel_id`.

---

Using the `channel_id` = `UCT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g` (which belongs to "[Microsoft HoloLens](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g)"), I use the ["channels" API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?hl=en) for retrieve the `uploads` playlist id.

Here is the URL request for retrieve the "`upload`" playlist id from the `channel_id` previously mentioned:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&fields=items(contentDetails%2FrelatedPlaylists%2Fuploads%2Csnippet%2Flocalized)&id=UCT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>
```

Explanation:

- **part**: set the **`snippet`** and **`contentDetails`** parts for retrieve the following:
- **fields**: from the **`snippet`** part: (**`localized`**, **`description`** and **`title`**) and from the **`contentDetails`** part: (**`relatedPlayLists`** and **`uploads`**).
- **id**: `channel_id` used in this request.

Here are the results from this request:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "localized": {
     "title": "Microsoft HoloLens",
     "description": "The official YouTube channel of Microsoft HoloLens. Transform your world with holograms. Visit HoloLens.com for more info."
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

> Check the value of the **`uploads`** property in the
>   **`contentDetails`** section. This value will be used in the next API request.

You can also check these results in the [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&id=UCT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g&fields=items(contentDetails%252FrelatedPlaylists%252Fuploads%252Csnippet%252Flocalized)&_h=7&) I prepared for make this request.

---

Once retrieved the **`uploads`** value *(as specified in previous lines)*, now it's time to use the ["playlistItems" API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en) for build the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&playlistId=UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%2CvideoPublishedAt)%2Csnippet%2Ftitle%2Cstatus)&maxResults=25&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>
```

Explanation:

- **part**: set the **`snippet`** and **`contentDetails`** parts for retrieve the following:
- **fields**: from the **`snippet`** part: (**`title`** and **`status`**) and from the **`contentDetails`** part: (**`videoId`** and **`videoPublishedAt`**).
- **playlistId**: is the `playlistId` used in this request - *(that is, the **`uploads`** value)*.
- **maxResults**: set to **`25`**.

Here are the results from this request:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Microsoft Windows Mixed Reality update | October 2018"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "00vnln25HBg",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-01-04T17:43:47.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "How to use Spectator View for mobile devices"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "3fXlPw_FGLg",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2018-10-15T17:13:42.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Microsoft HoloLens: Visualizing the next mission to Mars."
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "XVBbJ4EtAQY",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2018-07-02T16:30:26.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Microsoft HoloLens: Making mixed reality plug and play."
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "QwXcSekZKWE",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2018-06-25T23:25:55.000Z"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Microsoft HoloLens | Windows Mixed Reality HMD Exerciser"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "RU3OMjq_Yic",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2018-05-14T16:58:43.000Z"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I check the order of the items and they are in sorted by **`videoPublishedAt`** value *(new to old)*.

You can also check these results in the [try-it funcionality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A5%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22items(contentDetails(videoId%2CvideoPublishedAt)%2Csnippet%2Ftitle%2Cstatus)%22%7D#try-it) found in the YouTube Data API v3 - official documentation.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> For this case, I was unable to use the Google API Explorer *(as I used in the first request)* because I always got a "backend Error".

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

I think this is because the Google API explorer is outdated.

If anyone want to check it out, here is the [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&id=UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g&maxResults=25&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%252CvideoPublishedAt)%252Csnippet%252Ftitle%252Cstatus)%252CpageInfo&_h=17&).

Comment: I believe the issue is more complex than that, there are two publish dates, the date the video was uploaded to YouTube and the date the video went public.  The API returns the upload date and while the YouTube site itself (not the API) shows the publish date.  So there is no way to 100% reproduce the video list as seen on YouTube, at least not for channels that queue several videos in advance and then make them public in a different order.

Comment: Let me correct myself, you do get the correct publish date, but the entries are not neccessarily sorted by publish date, so trying to recreate how YouTube lists channels (with pagination) doesn't work (unless you want to retrieve the entire list for a channel and then sort it yourself, which adds a ton of bandwidth/quota overhead).

Comment: @bLight I'm affraid I can't understand, the uploads playlists did return the uploaded videos "where the first result is the most recent video and so on", can you share in your question a YouTube channel you're using for retrieve its uploaded videos and add in the same question the desired order? - my other suggestion is "if the YouTube channel has already the desired results", you can scrape such results. Without a clearer example, is difficult to understand you - due to language barrier, mostly.

Comment: Here's a sample channel : https://www.youtube.com/user/TheYoungTurks You will notice that the returned list of videos is not sorted by publish date using the playlistItems API branch.

Comment: @bLight if the results aren't ordered by publishDate, can you consider order the results yourself? or consider web-scraping `view-source:https:////www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UU1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ&disable_polymer=1`

Comment: Sorting myself would require downloading the entire channel, which can be 1000's of videos when I just want to replicate how YouTube is showing the channel's videos using pagination. The overhead of downloading an entire channel is just not worth it in my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using the playlist ID to get a list of videos, however mine do seem to be sorted by date from newest to oldest. Note that Youtube returns a page token that you can use to get the next 25 (or in my case 50) videos. I'm querying the API this way:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&pageToken=      not_used_for_first_query&fields=nextPageToken,items(snippet(publishedAt,title,desc ription,thumbnails(default(url)),resourceId(videoId)))&playlistId=uploads_playlist_id&maxResults=50&order=date&key=your_api_key`

This gets back in JSON response:

The video title
Publish date
Video description
Youtube URL for video
Video unique ID
Video thumbnail

You can see my working example at https://www.scriptbarrel.com

Comment: Also, I'm not having any problem with missing videos

Comment: Not all channels suffer from the video-out-of-order issue.  It only happens when they upload a video and don't publish it straight away, channels that upload & publish with no delay do not suffer from this issue.  Missing videos only occur using the Search API, not the Playlist API.