# Search list API not returning latest videos

Tags: youtube-data-api

I've been using the YouTube Data API's Search.list method to return the latest published videos for a specific channel.

The delay from video publish to appearing in the API has degraded over time.  Now it is no longer displaying the latest published videos.

I've used two variations of API parameters to get the latest published videos.

1) https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&channelId=[my-channel-id]&order=date&fields=items%28id%2FvideoId%2Csnippet%28publishedAt%2Ctitle%29%29&key=[my-key]

The url above uses the order parameter which sorts published videos in descending order.  Today is 2019-09-16 and the above only shows videos published up to 2019-09-12.  There are a hand full that have been published after 2019-09-12.

2) https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&publishedAfter=2019-09-12T00%3A00%3A00Z&maxResults=10&channelId=[my-channel-id]&order=date&fields=items%28id%2FvideoId%2Csnippet%28publishedAt%2Ctitle%29%29&key=[my-key]

The url above uses both the order and publishedAfter parameters.  This url returns videos published up to 2019-09-15, but is missing the latest on 2019-09-15... There were two published on 2019-09-15 alone.  I have ensured that it is not an issue with maxResults.

Are there any others experiencing issues with the Search.list method and/or experiencing similar inconsistencies?  Additional insight will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else arriving on this question, here's a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838213/4046124. In short, use the upload playlist, rather than the search API.